# What is the joint probability distribution of two same variables

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Let $f\left(x\right)$ be the probability density function of the
random variable $X$. What is the joint probability distribution of
$f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$ if $Y=X$?

Thanks for any helpful answer.

Comment: **Hint:** $f(x,y) = f(y|x) \cdot f(x)$. Now, for a fixed $x$, what must the conditional density $f(y|x)$ look like?

Comment: It seems like a Dirac delta function, right?

Comment: Right, so $f(x,y) = 0$ when $x \neq y$. What about when $x=y$?

Comment: @Macro Please help in this related question [Conditioning on probability zero: Can we say $P(B \le A|B=b) = P(b \le A|B=b)$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515364/conditioning-on-probability-zero-can-we-say-pb-le-ab-b-pb-le-ab-b)

Answer (score 8):

$X$ is **not** *jointly continuous* with itself in the sense that there is no joint density 
function (pdf) $f_{X,X}(s,t)$ that has positive value over a region of positive area 
in the plane
with coordinate axes $s$ and $t$.  All the probability mass lies on the straight line of slope $1$ through the origin (a region of zero area) and the joint cumulative
probability distribution
function CDF is
$$F_{X,X}(s,t) = P\{X \leq s, X \leq t\} = P\{X \leq \min(s,t)\} = F_X(\min(s,t)).$$
As whuber points out in the comments on another answer, 
$\frac{\partial^2F_{X,X}(s,t)}{\partial s\partial t}$ is not
defined for $s=t$.

Comment: Dilip Sarwate, please help in this related question [Conditioning on probability zero: Can we say $P(B \le A|B=b) = P(b \le A|B=b)$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515364/conditioning-on-probability-zero-can-we-say-pb-le-ab-b-pb-le-ab-b)

Answer (score 0):

$F_{(X,X)}(t,s) = P[X \le t,X \le s] = P[X \le \inf(s,t)]$

$f(s,t) = \frac{ \partial ^2F_{(X,X)}}{\partial s \partial t}(t,s) =  \frac{\partial^2 (P[X \le t] \Large{1_{\{s=t\}}})}{\partial^2  t } $

Where 
$\frac{\partial  \Large{1_{\{s=t\}}}}{\partial t}$
$= lim_{\sigma \mapsto 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma \pi}} e^{\frac{-s^2}{\sigma^2}}$
More info about the indicator function derivation are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: What does that second line mean?  How do you justify the two equalities? How do you even make sense of the last expression (the indicator function is not differentiable)?

Comment: $f$ is pdf and $F$ is the cdf. Maybe I missed something but : I consider case $s\not= t$ where the derivative is zero, and the other case where $s= t$ where it is not. In other words, I do not differentiate the indicator.

Comment: I see. Nevertheless, your manipulations do not appear to be correct. For example, let $X$ have a uniform distribution. Your conclusion is that $f(s,t)$ is identically zero, which is obviously false. One of the problems is clear: $F(t,s)$ is not differentiable where $s=t$.

Comment: Yes yes, my mistake: If everything apart from the derivative is clear, then yes  we do need to differentiate the indicator function wrt to $t$, the result will the delta function ( the result can be represented as a mathematical limit (of a gaussian when its variance tends to zeo,  , more info are here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Answer (score 0):

Random Discrete Variables Case:

For Y=X, 
then pij = 0 as xi and Xj are always exclusive
for i=j and pij=pi for i=j. as xi and xi to happen in the same time has pi chance.

So E[X^2] = E[XX] = Sum (xi^2*pi) for both cases

Comment: Please use proper math formatting, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex. The current answer is incomprehensible (for example, what are "xi" and "Xj" in "xi and Xj are always exclusive for i=j"?)  Though I don't think this answers the question in any case, as it is rather clear from the notation and wording that $X$ was intended to be continuous.

Comment: Dan and @JuhoKokkala , please help in this related question [Conditioning on probability zero: Can we say $P(B \le A|B=b) = P(b \le A|B=b)$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515364/conditioning-on-probability-zero-can-we-say-pb-le-ab-b-pb-le-ab-b)