# Conditioning on probability zero: Can we say $P(B \le A|B=b) = P(b \le A|B=b)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

Let $A,B$ be continuous random variables. Let $E,G,H$ be events. Let $t \in image(B)$.

(I forgot if any 2 continuous random variables necessarily have a well-defined joint pdf. If not, then assume joint pdf is well-defined whenever necessary.)

**Question**: Can we say $P(B \le A|B=t) = P(t \le A|B=t)$?

**What I've tried**: I think we're doing something like $P(E|H)=P(E \cap H|H)$, and I get it when $P(G|H)$ is defined for $P(H)>0$. What is being done here when technically $P(H)=0$? I mean, of course, in the 1st place when we say like '$P(\cdot|B=t)$', this is notational, we're not really conditioning on the $P$-null event $\{B=t\}$. But I still don't get exactly what's being done here. Well...

As I understand, $$RHS = P(t \le A|B=t) := \frac{\int_{t \le A} f_{A,B}(a,t) da}{\int_{\mathbb R} f_{A,B}(a,t) da} = \frac{\int_{t}^{\infty} f_{A,B}(a,t) da}{\int_{\mathbb R} f_{A,B}(a,t) da}$$

$$= \frac{\int_{t}^{\infty} f_{A,B}(a,t) da}{f_{B}(t)}= \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{f_{A,B}(a,t)}{f_{B}(t)} da,$$ where/whence $f_{A|B=t}(a) := \frac{f_{A,B}(a,t)}{f_{B}(t)}$.

That's all I got.

Not really sure how to evaluate LHS. Perhaps LHS := RHS, i.e. LHS is defined as RHS?

**Update**: Wait I think I have an idea how to do LHS

$$P(B \le A|B=t) = \int \int_{b \le a} f_{(A,B)|B=t}(a,b) da db$$

Here,

1. '$f_{(A,B)|B=t}(a,b)$' is I guess meant like $f_{(A,B)|T=t}(a,b)$ where $T$ is a random variable that is (not just almost surely but really) surely equal to $B$.
2. '$f_{(A,B)|T=t}(a,b)$' is meant like 2 random variables conditioned on a 3rd random variable. As I understand multivariate conditional joint distributions, we have this is $f_{(A,B)|T=t}(a,b) := \frac{f_{A,B,T}(a,b,t)}{f_T(t)}$ and then...
3. $$P(B \le A|B=t) = \int \int_{b \le a} f_{(A,B)|B=t}(a,b) da db = \int \int_{b \le a} \frac{f_{A,B,T}(a,b,t)}{f_T(t)} da db$$

$$= \int \int_{b \le a} \frac{f_{A,B,T}(a,b,t)}{\int \int_{(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2} f_{A,B,T}(a,b,t) da db} da db$$

$$= \frac{\int \int_{b \le a} f_{A,B,T}(a,b,t) da db}{\int \int_{(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2} f_{A,B,T}(a,b,t) da db} $$

4. And then I don't know. Apparently we might not be able to have a joint pdf if 2 of the random variables are surely equal (maybe even for almost surely):

   - 4.1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749370/joint-distribution-of-x-with-itself
   - 4.2. [What is the joint probability distribution of two same variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47162/what-is-the-joint-probability-distribution-of-two-same-variables)

Comment: yes, you can. another related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515333/absolute-value-of-uniform/515338#515338

Comment: @gunes thanks. how do you prove it? or is it like definition? or what? (or perhaps it's definition in elementary probability but then it becomes a theorem in advanced probability. but in advanced probability i don't recall learning conditioning on events of probability zero)

Comment: @gunes updated question. please help.